# Changing the trailing icon color in ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

I need to change the color of the trailing `keyboard_down_arrow` in `ExpansionTile`. I have tried wrapping it in Theme widget and setting accent, primary and IconTheme also, but nothing seems to work.

```
Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                    dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                    accentColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    //
                    title: Text("Some Text"
                    ),
                    childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    children: [
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to the above problem.

set `unselectedWidgetColor` property to the color you want in Theme class in flutter.

Comment: good do know you have found solution. Cheers

Comment: Do you also know how to change the color of the 'arrow up'? So the opposite of unselectedWidgetColor? Thanks

Comment: Found a way in this comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23053#issuecomment-606957087
Wrap the ExpansionTile in a Theme widget. E.g.:
Theme(
        data: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.black54),
        child: ExpansionTile()
)

Answer (score 17):

I have latest solution with both open/close state:

```
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white, // here for close state
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.white,
      ), // here for open state in replacement of deprecated accentColor
      dividerColor: Colors.transparent, // if you want to remove the border
    ),
    child: ExpansionTile(
        ...
    ),
),...
```

Comment: change colorSheme works

Answer (score 6):

To change the trailing icon Color you can use the fallowing parameter in Expansion Tile

```
 trailing: Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
```

**Example:**

```
 ExpansionTile(
                //
                title: Text("Some Text"),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
```

And for theme Color use `color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,`

Comment: this will make the arrow icon static and it will not rotate anymore.

Answer (score 3):

`ExpansionTile` has a properties:

```
iconColor: Colors.black,
collapsedIconColor: Colors.orange,
```

It changes the color of the trailing icon depending on if the tile is expanded or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more dynamic/general solution;

```
    ExpansionTileThemeData expansionTileTheme(ColorScheme colors) {
    return ExpansionTileThemeData(iconColor: Colors.white);
  }
```

use this theme data in your theme.dart file that you use for theme light & dark like this

```
   ThemeData light([Color? targetColor]) {
    final colorScheme = colors(Brightness.light, targetColor);
    return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      // unselectedWidgetColor: colorScheme.onPrimary,
      expansionTileTheme: expansionTileTheme(colorScheme),);
  }
```

in main.dart

```
 MaterialApp.router(            
  theme: theme.light(Color),
  );
```

This will affect your whole project, so you won't need to implement this color in every expansion tile that you will use.